# Infinite food, water and power

Tags: fallout-shelter

In the game I noticed I had full food, water and power for hours now, they never go down, it's bugged at full.

Yes I know it must seem nice to have it full but it makes all the people I have  on those stations useless. I even had all the dweller's leave the station to see if it affected anything and no it did not.

Answer (score 2):

No this doesn't seem to be a bug. I have the same situation. My food and water goes down if I'm in the game. If I leave it for a day it stays the same. It just goes down if I'm in it. Even Raider attacks stop if I leave the game for some hours. If I come back, the game is still in the raider attack.

You can try it on your own. Open your game, tab on your resource bars and make nothing. They should slowly count down. If your vault is quite big, you have a bigger storage of them. This may look like an infinite storage but in fact it's really counting down.

Comment: Missed the part where they said they removed everyone from their post huh?

Comment: No still the same answer. as it will decrease slowly.

Comment: i think OP is saying it _never_ goes down.

Comment: Yes and I mentioned he hasn't take a look at the numbers, only at the bars. I have nearly no power since 3 days, which means my food and water should drain. They do... of course. But currently the bar has moved for around ~5% for the last 3 days. If he take a look for a few hours, it would look like there is no change. This is the core of my answer.